# Starting a component in a Karaf feature

Tags: java, osgi, apache-felix, apache-karaf, karaf

I'm trying to deploy a feature which has a dependency to a component named "utils" the component was added as a feature like this:

```
<feature name="gc-utils" version="${version}">

        <bundle>mvn:org.eclipse.paho/org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3/1.0.2</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:log4j/log4j/1.2.17</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:commons-configuration/commons-configuration/1.10</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils/1.9.2</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:org.slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.7.12</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:org.apache.commons/commons-lang3/3.1</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:com.google.code.gson/gson/2.4</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:org.slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.12</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:my.bundle/utils/${version}</bundle>

</feature>
```

The feature do no starts because is missing the following constraint:

```
 executing command: Error executing command on bundles:
   Unable to execute command on bundle 118: Unresolved constraint in bundle utils [118]: Unable to resolve 118.0: missing requirement [118.0] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiri
ckage=sun.awt)
```

The thing is that I have no idea which bundle has `sun.awt`. I have the filling that is not abut finding this artifact, there is other side issue here.

anyone have an idea?

**UPDATE**
Alexander asked how the bundle is generated, and here is it the maven pom:

NOTE: tel me if anyone want the effective pom but this will be huge. This is why I didn't post neither the pom.xml nor the effective pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   <parent>
        <groupId>eu.linksmart.gc</groupId>
        <artifactId>eu.linksmart.gc.osgi.component</artifactId>
        <version>0.3.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

        <artifactId>utils</artifactId>
    <version>${linksmart.gc.version}</version>
    <name>Several Utils</name>
    <packaging>bundle</packaging>
    <dependencies>


        <dependency>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.paho</groupId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-configuration</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-configuration</artifactId>
            <version>1.10</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>Eclipse Paho Repo</id>
            <url>https://repo.eclipse.org/content/repositories/paho-releases/</url>
        </repository>

        <repository>
            <id>jboss-maven2-release-repository</id>
            <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>apache</id>
            <url>https://linksmart.eu/repo/content/repositories/apache-snapshots/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>attach-artifacts</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>attach-artifact</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <artifacts>
                            <artifact>
                                <file>src/main/resources/conf.cfg</file>
                                <type>cfg</type>
                                <classifier>configuration</classifier>
                            </artifact>
                        </artifacts>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
        <configuration>
            <instructions>
                <Bundle-SymbolicName>${project.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>

            </instructions>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Do you actually need the `sun.awt` classes at runtime? Are you building `utils` yourself or is it a 3rd party library? If you do not need sun.awt and if this is your own code, you should fix the imports of the utils bundle.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see your messages. Yes, it is my own code, and yes I don't need sun.awt. But the bundle says it needed

Comment: If it is your code and you are in control, why don't you fix the imports of the `util` bundle?

Comment: I do not import or add as dependency. Not sure where the constraint comes. Maybe is from one of the dependencies.

Comment: Please add information to your question about how you build the `util` bundle.

Comment: Same thing as before. Fix your bundle's imports if they are not needed at runtime or add the required sun packages to the boot class loader as Jonathan explained in his answer.

Comment: The jonathan fix do not work. I added in the jre.properties file and  the package is not loaded

Comment: Can you post the "my.bundle/util" MANIFEST.MF ? How is the MANIFEST.MF file generated ? Home mode, bnd, felix maven plugin ?

Comment: @AlexandreCartapanis I post it in the update

Comment: Can you also post the MANIFEST.MF content please ?

Answer (score 0):

sun.awt is a package from the JRE that karaf doesn't use automatically. You can modify your $KARAF_ETC/jre.properties and add a line in the jre you use to speciy karaf to provide more jre packages.

[You can find a similar resolution here](https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/servicemix-users/201203.mbox/%3C4F71EEA9.2060700@nanthrax.net%3E)

Comment: I'm impress. But didn't work. Is not shown in the `package:exports` and the message error is still there